# How to configure my Grails app to be used with Hibernate Tools on STS/Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using Grails on STS/Eclipse and want to use Hibernate Tools to test and simulate HQL queries. There is the **Hibernate Tools** add-on to Eclipse which is part of the **JBoss Tools**.

I could not figure out to make it working with Grails. Lets say I have a class:

```
class User {
  String name
  Date birthday
}
```

What do I have to do in order to make **Hibernate Tools** work correctly with my Grails project? Also I get the following error after I connected Hibernate to my database and project:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.JDBCMetaDataDialect.getTables(JDBCMetaDataDialect.java:26)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.processTables(JDBCReader.java:476)
at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCReader.java:74)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:126)
at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.readDatabaseSchema(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:115)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:65)
at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:106)
at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

How do I get my Grails project working with **Hibernate Tools**?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there was an incompatible API change with SLF4J between 1.5.x and 1.6.x.  You probably have version 1.5.x installed in your Eclipse, but hibernate tools is expecting 1.6.x.  I am not sure how you would have gotten into that state.  I am guessing that hibernate tools is requiring an incorrect version of slf4j.  More likely, the version constraint is too lenient and 1.5.5 is being used when it shouldn't.

Indeed, looking at the source code for Hibernate tools, the version is 1.5.8:

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-tools/blob/master/pom.xml#L135

I am not sure how to solve the problem, but it does look like a bug in hibernate tools.  They should change that to 1.6.1 or later.  I'd raise an issue with them or post on their mailing list.  You can find out where to do that here:

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-tools